# Should double factorials be under the factorial tag?

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-wikis

There has just recently ben created a [double-factorial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/double-factorial) tag. I don't think we should have another tag just for this and that the tag [factorial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/factorial) suits it well enough. I propose we change the tag wiki for [factorial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/factorial) to include double factorials and remove the [double-factorial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/double-factorial) tag.

Comment: Or we could even make (double-factorial) a [synonym of (factorial)](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/factorial/synonyms). Creating a [tag synonym](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-how-do-they-work) means, that whenever someone tags their question (double-factorial), the tag is automatically changed to (factorial).

Comment: Seeing that double integrals and triple integrals merrily live under (integration), I think double factorials need not try to secede from (factorial).

Comment: I fully agree with the comments from @MartinSlezak and CareBear. When using double factorials we typically use also factorials in the same calculation. This split would be too fine-grained for a part of factorials which has not that importance. And if we would use a tag *double-factorial* what about introducing another tag *triple-factorial*? :-)

Comment: It's worth noting that $(x!)!\ne x!!$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that everyone agrees that we should not have a tag named double-factorial, I have changed the tag of the single question with double factorial to factorial and the double factorial tag should shortly delete itself assuming no new questions get added to the tag